# Which version of SQL Server am I running?

Tags: sql-server, versioning

I am looking for a SQL Query which will help me differentiate between the various versions of SQL Server:

2000/2005/2008

Development/Standard/EE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tend to use this short script:

```
SELECT  
    SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') as 'Product Version', 
    SERVERPROPERTY('productlevel') as 'Patch Level',  
    SERVERPROPERTY('edition') as 'Product Edition',
    SERVERPROPERTY('buildclrversion') as 'CLR Version',
    SERVERPROPERTY('collation') as 'Default Collation',
    SERVERPROPERTY('instancename') as 'Instance',
    SERVERPROPERTY('lcid') as 'LCID',
    SERVERPROPERTY('servername') as 'Server Name'
```

which gives me an output something like:

```
Product Version Patch Level Product Edition             CLR Version Default Collation   Instance    LCID    Server Name
10.0.2531.0     SP1         Developer Edition (64-bit)  v2.0.50727  Latin1_General_CI_AS    NULL    1033    XYZABC
```

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT @@version
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this will help you http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185

Answer (score 1):

Will

```
Select @@version
```

suffice?

Answer (score 1):

Select @@Version

On my system, this returns:

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (x64) Mar 29 2009 10.11.52 Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporate Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0  (Build 6002: Service Pack 2)

Answer (score 0):

We will use simple technique to detect the server type using the serverproperty('ProductVersion') for a list of options visit
SERVERPROPERTY (Transact-SQL). So lets see what are the pros and cons

```
DECLARE @sql2005Code varchar(255)             

SET @sql2005Code = 'print ''SQL 2005 Code'' '

DECLARE @ver nvarchar(128)

SET @ver = CAST(serverproperty('ProductVersion') AS nvarchar)

SET @ver = SUBSTRING(@ver, 1, CHARINDEX('.', @ver) - 1)

        -- SQL 2000

IF ( @ver = '8' ) BEGIN

        print 'SQL 2000'

END

        -- SQL 2005

ELSE IF ( @ver = '9' )BEGIN

  exec (@sql2005Code)

END
```

Here is my full entry on this hope this helps you.
[Detect SQL server version](http://www.gregbugaj.com/?p=88)

Answer (score 0):

The *shortest* SQL query is [`xp_msver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187372.aspx)

But `SELECT @@VERSION` does what you want